# Scaling points of one variable in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting quiz question performance data using ggplot. The quiz has two groups of questions, random and mandatory. The graph below shows both groups being scaled by how many attempts were taken for those questions. However, both groups are being scaled and I would only like the random 30 group to be scaled to size of attempts. I've also provided a part of my code below that will scale both groups (I can't add the data here as it has confidential information). Thank you in advance!

[Average score vs point biserial plot, both variables scaled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNyeG.png)

```
ggplot(weekData, aes(x=firstPB, y=firstAverageQScore))+
  geom_point(aes(colour=section, size=questionAttempt))+
  labs(size="Number of attempts")+
  geom_smooth(method = glm, se= F) +
  ggtitle(paste0("Week ",week," First Attempts")) +
  xlab("Point Biserial") + xlim(-1,1)+
  ylab("Average Score for Question(%)") + ylim(0,100) +
  geom_label_repel(aes(label=number), alpha=0.5,max.overlaps = Inf)+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype="dashed",
             color = "black", size=0.5)+
  scale_colour_discrete(name="Group",
                       breaks=c("random", "mandatory"),
                       labels=c("Random 30","Mandatory 10")) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", 
                                        colour = "white",
                                        size = 0.5, linetype = "solid")) +
  annotate("rect", xmin=(0.25), xmax=(Inf), 
           ymin=(30), ymax=(70), fill="#b1b3b133")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I would suggest two things to help you get useful help. 1) Can you clarify what you mean by "scaled"? Are you referring to the size aesthetic, or do you mean an adjustment to some of the values prior to this code?  2) If you can't share your real data, you can share fake data like `weekData <- data.frame(section = c("Random 30", "Mandatory 10"), firstPB = 0.5, firstAverageQScore = c(80, 85), questionAttempt = c(10, 60), number = 1:2); week = 10` Just needs to have same structure and data types of the real data so that your code runs.

Comment: On an unrelated note, I would suggest using `scale_size_area() +` when you intend to communicate counts. This does two things, first ensuring that a plot reflecting a value of 0 has no area, and it corresponds with the intuition that the area (not the radius) of the point is proportional to the value.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a crack at some fake data to try out a solution:

```
weekData <- data.frame(section = c("random", "mandatory"), 
                       firstPB = c(0,0.1,0.2,0.3), 
                       firstAverageQScore = c(80, 85), 
                       questionAttempt = c(10, 10, 60, 60), 
                       number = 1:4)

#    section firstPB firstAverageQScore questionAttempt number
#1    random     0.0                 80              10      1
#2 mandatory     0.1                 85              10      2
#3    random     0.2                 80              60      3
#4 mandatory     0.3                 85              60      4

week = 10  # used in title
```

One way to approach this would be to use two layers for the display, which each see different subsets of the data. One maps `questionAttempt` to size, the other has size hard coded:

```
ggplot(weekData, aes(x=firstPB, y=firstAverageQScore))+
  geom_point(data = subset(weekData, section == "random"),
             aes(colour=section, size=questionAttempt))+
  geom_point(data = subset(weekData, section != "random"),
             aes(colour=section), size = 5)+
  ...
```

That gives me this, where you can see that Mandatory has uniform size even though the associated `questionAttempt` values vary:

[image]

Perhaps a simpler approach could be to define the value in the mapping, so that we override the values coming in if the section is not "random":

```
geom_point(aes(colour=section, 
           size=if_else(section=="random", questionAttempt, 50)))+
```